# Received data PHP->AJAX (C:\inetpub\wwwroot) but how to pass them over to html file in a different directory?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm using the IIS localhost for my PHP. The default path is C:\inetpub\wwwroot. I'm using an AJAX request which is in the same folder but I want to pass the data over to a different html file which has a path for instance C:\newfolder. Can it be done ?

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

$sql = "SELECT FirstName FROM customers where ID=1";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
      //echo $row['FirstName']."<br />";
echo json_encode(array('name'=>$row),JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>
```

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open('GET', 'test.php', true);
  xmlhttp.onload = function(){
      if(this.status == 200){
        let data = this.responseText;
        let jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
        retrieve(jsondata.name.FirstName);
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.send();
    function retrieve(parser){
      console.log("funct",parser);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need run app or file on different url IMO, it is setup of your IIS.

Comment: Ajax is just a HTTP(S) request that goes through the web server, just like when you access a page "manually" through the browser. For an Ajax call to work, the target needs to be accessible using HTTP(S) as well so you can't call any files "outside" of the web server.